# intel xdk methods not working! works on xdk app preview but not work when I build the app

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, intel

I am creating a simple button using bootstrap (html5 + cordova). It works in intel's app preview app, but when I install it on my Android it is not working.

- tested it on html5 only still not working.
- I have ticked launch external app domain tickmark in intel xdk

app.js

```
function feedback() {

     var bodyText = 'write your message here';
        intel.xdk.device.sendEmail(bodyText, "amir329@icloud.com", "", true, "", "" );

}
```

index.html

```
<button onclick="feedback();">feedback</button>
```

check images

[image]

Comment: in html file its like this < button onclick="feedback();"> feedback </button>

Comment: If you indent your code using four spaces, it will be displayed correctly. This time, I have edited the question for you. :)

Comment: oh sure and sorry...my first time..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. This guy has made a plugin which is working. and i am using it now.. https://github.com/krisrak/html5-cordova-plugin-sharing